# Setting AuthnContextClassRef in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, saml-2.0

I am rather new to SAML, specifically integrating applications with Keycloak. I am running into an issues with `<AuthnContextClassRef>` that's part of `<AuthnContext>`. The requirements from the SP state that the URN needs to end with `PasswordProtectedTransport`. The output I am getting in the returned SAML assertion is ending with `unspecified`:

My output: `<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>`

Desired output: `<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>`

Where can I define this in Keycloak?

Comment: Did you find this out by any chance?

Comment: @AliKazmi I didn't figure this out. It turns out this wasn't relevant to the issue I was experiencing.

Comment: How are you implementing this in Keycloak. If you have any repo or example you can share pls.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this : [Keycloak always returns urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified AuthnContextClassRef unless AuthnStatement inclusion is disabled. If you need to handle authncontext properly, please open a JIRA feature request.](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-January/009298.html)

But I didn't sure about if the correction is made.

Comment: Thus, existing one JIRA ticket since the version 3.5 but now we are actual in 9 or 10, this ticket stand always (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-5224?_sscc=t)

Comment: Keycloak 15 is released, this prob was fixed.